# Does rails automatically give you the add/edit/destroy form for tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following a tutorial which is relatively new on rails. It is a rather large course which goes making through several applications and its going quite well so far. The only thing I'm wondering is that, theres this whole section in the series before we actually start our application on

```
Creating Articles
Destroying Articles
Editing
and etc
```

I'm writing notes down and finding the experience quite good. However for some reason. When I go to my webpage /articles, I already find that there is a table made for me, and the `destroy,edit,new` functions are already available for me to use!

Does the newer version of rails automatically provide this for you? I was wondering because I think it would be a good opportunity to add these myself, but I feel like If I delete the wrong things and try to do it myself, I might mess up other things that are part of the core rails application.

**TLDR**

Do the newer versions of rail making adding / deleting articles easier by prepackaging them for you? Also is there a way to make it so that it doesn't add these features, so I can practice coding them in myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used [Scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding). It auto-generates all the routes, model, controller, and views for a particular class (say, for instance, `Article`). You probably were asked to run something like this:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Article
```

Personally, I haven't ever used this professionally. You can certainly delete the forms/views/anything and redo them yourself.

Comment: Yes I remember doing that!!! Should I not type that in next time? So I can do it myself?

Comment: If you are using everything that it provides, it's a simple way of getting up and running. I usually never use everything (maybe I don't use the `index` route, for instance).

Comment: Ok after the basics of this tutorial , I'm going to try and recreate the whole destroy, edit, add new article page on my own, that should be a good exercise I guess right?

Comment: And yes, you can create the files (that you want) yourself. Remember to put them in the correct place and name them correctly. I would keep the scaffold you have until you are familiar with it all.

Comment: Thanks. I just got confused because there is so many syntax that seems quite random to me. Coming from standard programming languages it just seems odd. I will keep practising!

Comment: So If I want to practise this on my own, should I just mkdir, and make another rails test app and try it on there?

Comment: Yeah, you should, of course, always use `rails new (appname)` to actually create the app. But practice is always good.

Answer (score 0):

The basic ideas is called [scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate). When you run this code in your terminal window `rails generate scaffold user`, it will automatically create the following:

1. A model class named User
2. A controller class named UsersController, with 7 restful routes
3. A view directory called users with a few views

This is just to help you get up and running faster. If you look at the example terminal output in the link, it shows you all the files it creates/modifies for you.

Comment: Thanks, I want to try coding it on my own,so next time I'm going to try creating it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have used **scaffold** generator. It will prepare **CRUD**(Create, Read, Update and Delete) operations for you. We used it generally when we are in hurry to have CRUD functionality. As a beginner, it would be a great if we perform CRUD operations at owns.

This link will be a good help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Thank you.